# Prove that $f_1''$ and $f_2'''$ have a root

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $a<b$ and $g\in C^3([a,b])$ (means that $g$ can be differentiated three times on $[a,b]$) and

(1)   $f_1(x)=(x-a)^2(b-x)g(x)$

(2)   $f_2(x)=(x-a)^2(b-x)^2g(x)$

Prove that $f_1''$ and $f_2'''$ have a root in $[a,b]$.

---

Tried to use the Theorem of Rolle but get stucked. Any help on this?

Comment: first degree polynomial and zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f_1(x)=(x-a)^2(b-x)g(x)$

$f'_1(x)=2(x-a)(b-x)g(x)-(x-a)^2g(x)+(x-a)^2g'(x)$

Using Rolle's Theorem twice:

$f_1(a)=f_1(b)=0$, $\exists \lambda \in (a,b)$ such that $f'_1(\lambda)=0$

$f'_1(a)=f'_1(\lambda)=0$, $\exists \mu \in (a,\lambda)$ such that $f''_1(\mu)=0$

---

$f_2(x)=(x-a)^2(b-x)^2g(x)$

$f'_2(x)=2(x-a)(b-x)^2g(x)-2(x-a)^2(b-x)g(x)+(x-a)^2(x-b)^2g'(x)$

Using Rolle's Theorem thrice:

$f_2(a)=f_2(b)=0$, $\exists \xi \in (a,b)$ such that $f'_2(\xi)=0$

$f'_2(a)=f'_2(\xi)=f'_2(b)=0$, $\exists \eta \in (a,\xi)$, $\zeta \in (\xi,b)$ such that $f''_2(\eta)=0$ and  $f''_2(\zeta)=0$

$f''_2(\eta)=f''_2(\zeta)=0$, $\exists \omega \in (\eta,\zeta)$ such that $f'''_2(\omega)=0$